# Bind a list with jquery datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have made an MVC application which would display a set of file names located in a given directory. To display the list, i have used normal table in my view.Since the view returns a huge list of file names, i am asked to use jquery datatable,which i dont have much idea about. I tried by going through lot of suggestions but could not return the list at all. Please have a look at the code below.

**Controller:**

```
public class SupportingChannelController : Controller
{
// GET: SupportingChannel
List<SupportingChannel> _list = null;
SupportingChannelBL _bl = new SupportingChannelBL();
SupportingChannelDataVM _data = new SupportingChannelDataVM();
public ActionResult GetSupportingChannelData()
{
_list = _bl.channel();

_data._model = _list;
return View("SupportingChannel", _data);
}
```

**View**

```
@model MultiRequestInterface.Models.SupportingChannelDataVM
@{
ViewBag.Title = "SupportingChannel";
}

<h2>Supporting Channels</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("getComType","SupportingChannel",FormMethod.Post))
{

<div>

<style>
table,th,td
{
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
align-content:center;
}
</style>
<div style="border:solid;width:100%;overflow-x:auto;">
<table  id="table" align="center" style="width:100%" class="display">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Communication Type</th>
<th>Communication Description</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
if (TempData["testmsg"] != null)
{
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("@TempData["testmsg"]");
</script>
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
{
var table = $('#table').DataTable();
var data = table.data;
$.ajax({
url: 'GetSupportingChannelData/SupportingChannel',
dataType: 'json',
contentType: "application/json;",
data: JSON.stringify(data),
success: function () {


},

});
});
</script>
```

Since i am returning a list to the view, i just want some help as in howcan i pass this list as data to the jquery datatable..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your target URL seems to be wrong (`url: 'GetSupportingChannelData/SupportingChannel',` => this is invalid URL because `SupportingChannel` is a controller name). Also the target action method returns view page, you need to add an action method which returns `JsonResult` to add list data as JSON for `DataTable`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto. could you please suggest me an example as to how can  i do that...?

Answer (score 2):

Since you've already created HTML table containing column headers, just use built-in AJAX call function in `DataTable` to fetch data as JSON:

```
$('#table').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "@Url.Action("GetSupportingChannelData", "SupportingChannel")", // action method URL
        "type": "GET",
        "datatype": "json"
    },
    , columns: [
            { data: 'columnName1' },
            { data: 'columnName2' },
            { data: 'columnName3' },
            { data: 'columnName4' },
            { data: 'columnName5' }
    ],
    // other settings
});
```

Then use return type `JsonResult` to return your list of model as JSON data that will passed to `DataTable` (I assumed there is another action method which returns view where `DataTable` should belongs to):

```
public class SupportingChannelController : Controller
{
    List<SupportingChannel> _list = null;
    SupportingChannelBL _bl = new SupportingChannelBL();

    // other class-level fields

    // returns view to render DataTable
    public ActionResult GetChannelData()
    {
         return View();
    }

    // returns JSON data from list of model values
    public ActionResult GetSupportingChannelData()
    {
         // other stuff

         _list = _bl.channel();

         // other stuff

         return Json(new { data = _list }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Additional references:

[Implement jQuery Datatable in ASP.NET MVC application](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2015/11/implement-jquery-datatable-in-aspnet-mvc.html)

[AJAX CRUD Operation With jQuery DataTables In ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ajax-crud-operation-with-jquery-datatables-in-asp-net-mvc-5-for-beginners/)